# creating complex dictionary from string with multiple keys in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm getting output string in format like this:

```
w = "name: some name|age: 23|street: some address|favorite meal: meal|name: some other name|age: 15|street: some other address|pet: dog|name: <and so on..>"
```

The issue is that this string is not fully predictable, the info after "name" until another "name" belongs to the given person and the "keys" for that info could be more than one word ( although I think I can estimate/predict all the "key words")

Is there a way to arrange this into python dictionary ? ( I guess this would require dictionary with another dictionary as its value... but how would I extract all the info from the string and keep the relevant data together ( the string is much longer around 10 people in one )

Comment: Does each entry always start with `name`?

Comment: Split you string at `|` before name (Regex: `\|(?=name)`) Then split on `|` to get key-value-strings. Then you can split those at `:` again and put that in a dictionary. By the way, I guess you mean a list of dicts which contain a dict for every person, right!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use each 'name' key as a marker:

```
w = "name: some name|age: 23|street: some address|favorite meal: meal|name: some other name|age: 15|street: some other address|pet: dog"

output = []
current = {}
for item in w.split('|'):
    key_value = item.split(':')
    key = key_value[0].strip()
    value = key_value[1].strip()
    if key == 'name':
        current = {key:value}
        output.append(current)
    else:
        current[key] = value


print(output)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'some name', 'age': '23', 'street': 'some address', 'favorite meal': 'meal'}, {'name': 'some other name', 'age': '15', 'street': 'some other address', 'pet': 'dog'}]
```

Comment: thanks worked like a charm, did some modifications to fit perfectly, but you helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
w = "name: some name|age: 23|street: some address|favorite meal: meal|name: some other name|age: 15|street: some other address|pet: dog|"
new_w = re.split('(?<=\|)name:\s|(?<=^)name:\s', w)
new_data = {i.split('|')[0]:{b[:b.index(':')]:b[b.index(':')+2:] for b in filter(lambda x:x, i.split('|')[1:])} for i in filter(lambda x:x, new_w)}
```

Output:

```
{'some name': {'favorite meal': 'meal', 'age': '23', 'street': 'some address'}, 'some other name': {'pet': 'dog', 'age': '15', 'street': 'some other address'}}
```